# Speed is different when differentiating a function and when not differentiating

Tags: velocity, differentiation

I have the function, $S(t) = t^2$.
When Finding speed $= V = \frac{dS}{dt}$, we get $V = 2t$. 
Now If, I don't differentiate it and simply put

$V = \frac{Distance(S)}{Time(t)} = \frac{t^2}{t}$

We get $V = t$, which is just half the earlier one. Can you please explain why is this happening?

Comment: What's the difference between the mean speed and the instantaneous speed? Drawing a graph of your S function, and determining those two speeds graphically may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body starts from zero velocity at time $t=0$ and undergoes a constant acceleration.
Your first method gives the final velocity at the end of the time interval $t$ and the second method gives the average velocity over that time period from $t=0$ to time $t$.

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate $V(t) = \frac{dS(t)}{dt}$,
then you get the *momentary* speed at time $t$.

When you calculate $V(t) = \frac{S(t)}{t}$ which is
$\frac{S(t)-S(0)}{t-0}$ in your case,
then you get the *average* speed in the time-range between $0$ and $t$.

These two are different, because your movement is accelerating, i.e. speed is growing with time.